# how do you use the append function and then remove a shape from the list?

Tags: python

I am struggling completing this assignment for my computer science class, the task says:

> Create a program that uses Turtle to draw shapes. Show the following menu:
>
> - Enter Circle
> - Enter Rectangle
> - Remove Shape
> - Draw Shapes
> - Exit
>
> Circles – User inputs position, radius, and color. The position is the CENTER of the circle
>
> Rectangles – User inputs position, height, width, color. The position is the lower left-hand corner
>
> Colors – Allow red, yellow, blue, and green only
>
> Remove – Show the number of items in the list and let the user enter a number and remove that shape from the list. You may assume that they only enter a number within the range that you display.
>
> Draw Shapes – Draw the shapes in the order they are in the list. Clear the screen if shapes had been drawn before. The color is the fill color of the shape. Shapes are only drawn after this selection, not after entering or removing a shape.
>
> Guidelines
>
> Create a class called Circle in its own file called circle.py
>   Create a class called Rectangle in its own file called rectangle.py
>   In each class create a method called draw() that will draw the shape (as well as any other methods you need)
>   Store all Circle and Rectangle objects in a single list
>   Use a loop to draw all of the shapes
>   Create a file called assn13-task3.py that contains a main() function to run your program
>   '''

This is what I have written so far but I am stuck on the "Remove" and "Draw Shapes" and not sure what it means or what to code

[image]

(I have the modules circle and rectangle have all of the turtle functions to draw them, I just didn't show them in the question)

Comment: please include your code as text in your question, not as an image

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [Ask] and take the [Tour].